What makes one USB 3.0 flash drive faster than the other?
I have two USB storage devices:

SanDisk Extreme Portable SSD SDSSDE60-500G: According to spec it supports USB 3.1.
SanDisk Ultra Flair USB 3.0 Flash Drive SDCZ73: According to spec it supports USB 3.0.

I decided to benchmark both on an old motherboard (Gigabyte GA-AM1M-S2H (rev. 1.1)) with only a USB 3.0 port.
The benchmark results were a bit surprising. While the Ultra Flair got reading speeds that I would expect from USB 3.0, the Extreme Portable got twice higher speeds.
Is the fact that this device supports 3.1 make it faster with 3.0? Or is it a byproduct as the designers made it read faster internally which makes it faster both with 3.0 and 3.1?
Ultra Flair:
sudo hdparm -t --direct /dev/sdc 

/dev/sdc: Timing O_DIRECT disk reads: 408 MB in 3.01 seconds = 135.64 MB/sec

Extreme Portable:
sudo hdparm -t --direct /dev/sdc

/dev/sdc: Timing O_DIRECT disk reads: 984 MB in 3.00 seconds = 327.79 MB/sec


The same that makes one internal SSD faster than the other: Everything but the interface.

Feel free to close it. I got my answer. Also, I was not aware that external SSD and thumb drive are intrinsically different.

The USB interface sets a cap on how fast the drive can go, the actual flash storage and controller set the actual speed that the drive runs at.
From Wikipedia the speeds are:

USB 3.0: 5 Gbit/s (500 MB/s, USB 3.0)
USB 3.1: 10 Gbit/s (1.212 GB/s, USB 3.1 Gen 2)
USB 3.2: 20 Gbit/s (2.422 GB/s, USB 3.2 Gen 2x2)

Neither of your drives actually saturate USB 3.0 speeds, though with overheads the Extreme Portable is somewhere close.
Note that the usable speed of USB 3.0 is considered to be around 400MB/s when accounting from protocol overheads. From that Wikipedia USB 3 page:

Accounting for the encoding overhead, the raw data throughput is 4 Gbit/s, and the specification considers it reasonable to achieve 3.2 Gbit/s (400 MB/s) or more in practice

These are just the theoretical maximum speeds of the interface between the drive and the computer. You'll notice that USB 3.0 should be fine for both of your drives. The reason for using faster interfaces is going to be down to economics, part availability, future-proofing and removing performance bottlenecks, probably between the flash controller and the flash itself as newer controllers are likely to handle the flash better.
Higher speed interfaces also allow the controller to "burst" data across the USB bus faster and put that side into a lower power mode while it waits for the flash to return the next block of data to be sent. It may well be that the controller USB transmitter going to sleep for short periods can save it from overheating.
What your actual speeds are going to be limited by is the actual flash storage on the device itself.
It will be down to the various characteristics of the flash memory. How many parallel data channels there are to the controller, whether the flash has some kind of block request queue, how much data it reads ahead, what the flash arrangement is.
Generally though, the more you pay or the newer you buy, the better and faster the flash memory and controller will be.
